# Dynamic Attribute value from controller how to work with

Tags: angularjs

Sample html and controller is given below. I want to add attribute value dynamically which is not working. How to make it workable?

HTML:

```
 <div ng-controller="WidgetsController" style="margin-top:5px;padding-top:5px">
                        <ul style="margin-top:0px;padding-top:0px">
                            <li style="margin:5px; float: none;"  ng-repeat="tab in tabs"
                                ng-class="{active:isActiveTab('/{{tab.title}}')}">
                              <!--  <a href="#/{{tab.title}}">{{tab.title}}</a>-->
                           <a ui-sref=".{{tab.title}}" class="btn btn-primary">{{tab.title}}</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
```

Angular's code:

```
routerApp.controller('WidgetsController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.tabs = [{
            title: 'New'
        },
        {
           title: 'EDIT'
        }  
    ];
});
```

Comment: What is the error? what is "isActiveTab"?

Comment: is for css to apply anyway i can remove it but main thing how to work with dynamic ui-sref attribute.